# Reusing a java lambda function

Tags: java, lambda

I have a Map as follows:

```
Map<String, String> inputMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I have a lambda function as follows, which updates the above map

```
Arrays.asList(new String[]{"value1", "value2"}).forEach(p -> inputMap.put(p, "someValue"));
```

This lambda will be reused frequently in the codebase, and I want to be able to easily track it as all occurrences will likely be removed at a later date.

I'm thinking the easiest way is to introduce a static method in a class (static as it will likely never need to be polymorphic and in unit tests will not need to be mocked)... Something like

```
public static void addProperties(final Map<String, String> inputMap, String value, final String...keys) {
    Arrays.asList(keys).forEach(p -> inputMap.put(p, value));
}
```

The issue here is that I'm introducing a side effect as the inputMap will be updated by the void method - I could create a copy of the inputMap and return that but I'm wondering if this is becoming overkill for what I'm trying to achieve

What is the best way to achieve reusability in this scenario?

Comment: In your method, why don't you just do `for (String key :  keys) { inputMap.put(key, value); }`. I don't see the need to create a list first.  And the only problem I could foresee is if multiple threads could access the map at the same time.

Comment: Should be "keys" probably, not "values". I'm going with overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Updating an existing map and creating a new map are rather different things, so you may want to have two separate methods for these tasks:

```java
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> newMap(V value, K ... keys) {
    return Arrays.stream(keys)
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                k -> k,
                k -> value
            ));
}

public static<K, V> void updateMap(Map<K, V> mutableMap, V value, K ... keys) {
    mutableMap.putAll(newMap(value, keys));
}
```